# Convert feet and inches from varchar to float in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want to convert lengths in feet and inches from varchar to float using a select statement.

Example:

8' --> 8

8'11" --> 8.9167

9'5" --> 9.4167

3'10.5" --> 3.875

I am using this function at the moment. But it messes up with some of the values like 0'0.5", NULL, blanks, etc. Thanks in advance.

```
  CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[convert_detail_code]
(
    @detail_code varchar(64)
)
RETURNS float
AS BEGIN
    declare @length float
    declare @temp int
    declare @stringlen int
    declare @inches varchar(64)
    declare @fraction float

    set @length = 0

    if (@detail_code = '') or (@detail_code is null) begin
        set @length = 0
    end
    else begin
        set @temp = CharIndex('''',@detail_code)

        if @temp > 0 begin
            set @length = Convert(float,(Left(@detail_code,@temp-1)))
        end

        set @temp = CharIndex ('"',@detail_code)

        if @temp > 0 begin
            set @stringlen = @temp - CharIndex ('''',@detail_code) - 1
            set @inches = LTRIM(RTRIM(SubString (@detail_code, @temp - @stringlen, @stringlen)))
            set @temp = CharIndex (' ',@inches)
            if @temp > 0
            BEGIN
                set @length = @length + Convert (float, SubString(@inches,1,@temp)) / 12
                set @inches = SubString(@inches,@temp+1,LEN(@inches)-@temp)
                set @fraction = (Convert(float,SubString(@inches,1,CharIndex('/',@inches)-1)) / Convert(float,SubString(@inches,CharIndex('/',@inches)+1,Len(@inches)-CharIndex('/',@inches))))/Cast(12 as float)
                set @length = @length + @fraction
            END
            else
            BEGIN
                if charIndex('/',@inches) > 0
                begin
                    set @fraction = (Convert(float,SubString(@inches,1,CharIndex('/',@inches)-1)) / Convert(float,SubString(@inches,CharIndex('/',@inches)+1,Len(@inches)-CharIndex('/',@inches))))/Cast(12 as float)
                    set @length = @length + @fraction
                end
                else
                begin
                    set @length = @length + Convert (float, @inches) / 12.0
                end
            END
        end
    end

    return @length
end

GO
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? Why are you doing this in SQL and not your presentation or data input layer?

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you were just storing the number of inches, instead of storing it in this format...

Comment: Try a scalar function - if you are having trouble with that come back and show your progress and you'll get help with specific questions.

Comment: A conversion like this is hideously involved in T-SQL. You will either end up with a scalar-valued function with terrible performance, or an incomprehensible mess of an inline table-valued function with slightly better performance. If you *must* do this in the database, strongly consider writing a CLR function to do this, as it's much easier in a proper programming language. From SQL Server 2016 onwards, it's more practical (since we have [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt684588), which you really want here).